# Pip install doesn't add module to python in Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, azure, pip

I want to run a python script in Microsoft Azure. For that purpose I followed the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python).

Downloaded the sample code, ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`, got a message that `flask` was installed successfully but when I ran `python main.py` , I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

If I open python and run `help('modules')` , flask is not listed there although I supposedly just installed it. I have the same problem with other modules.

Comment: What is the result if you run the command `pip freeze`

Comment: also not listed there.

Comment: Tried to update pip to the latest version (`pip install --upgrade pip`), this also doesn't work. I get the message:

`Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.0
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.0:`

But after running `pip install flask` again, I get the same warning that pip is outdated...

Comment: What happen if you install a package, for example, `numpy` and then call it in a python shell?

Comment: as usual, says it was installed but it was not installed: https://pastebin.com/L7Y0E86g

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to install flask and any other package using virtualenv:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install flask
```

Comment: Happens the same as with `numpy`. I ran the `pip install` command but it never installs it for some reason. Sample output here: https://pastebin.com/L7Y0E86g

Comment: I change the answer, I'm not sure but it may be helpful. tell me what happens.

Comment: Maybe you have to contact support of Azure, but if there is no obligation for staying in Microsoft Azure, I suggest you to go somewhere else like pythonanywhere.com. For now, I don't know that is the problem and how you have to solve it, but if I found time I will signup to Azure and try to find out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory that you have cloned the hello world application into. In this case, it would be the **python-docs-hello-world** folder. Type in `pip list`. This should list all the installed packages in the current python environment.

Your output should look like:

```
PS D:\python_code\stackoverflow\python-docs-hello-world> pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------
click        6.7
Flask        0.12.1
itsdangerous 0.24
Jinja2       2.10
MarkupSafe   1.0
pip          10.0.1
setuptools   39.1.0
Werkzeug     0.14.1
wheel        0.31.0
PS D:\python_code\stackoverflow\python-docs-hello-world>
```

If your `pip list` command does not list these packages, please try the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command again inside the `python-docs-hello-world` directory. If that doesn't work ( I don't see a reason why, still..) you can always install the required packages one by one with the `pip install packagename` command.

Cheers :)

Comment: The whole point of this post is that this doesn't work. See output here: https://pastebin.com/DJVK2QSc